# Resize multiple paragraph text frames in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, paragraph

in Photoshop CS2 is it possible to resize (and not transform) more than one paragraph text frames at a time?

can you help me please? many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight all the text layers in the Layers Panel. (Use Shift-click or Ctrl/Command-click to select multiple layers.)

Change the type size.

All the layers will update.

If you mean resize the frame around the paragraph text, then no. You have to do that one at a time.

Comment: In fact, I mean resize the frame around the paragraph text.

Comment: In newer version of Photoshop is it possible to do it? Thanks!

Comment: No. Even if the version released yesterday you must still resize text frames one at a time.